# Android Query Image don't display

Tags: android, image, aquery

AQuery used Image don't display

I'm use progressbar and AQuery Image

Data does not come out, but turns progress.

==== code ====

ArrayList arrData in data

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    URLConnection connection;
    AQuery localAQuery = new AQuery(convertView);

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toplist, parent, false);
    }

    //ImageView mImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.iconItem);

    ((AQuery)localAQuery.id(R.id.gameTitle)).text(arrData.get(position).getGameTitle());
    ((AQuery)localAQuery.id(R.id.gameContent)).text(arrData.get(position).getGameContent());
    ((AQuery)localAQuery.id(R.id.gamePay)).text(arrData.get(position).getRewardPrice());

    if(arrData.get(position).getImage().equals(""))
        ((AQuery)localAQuery.id(R.id.iconItem)).image(R.drawable.logo);
        //mImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
    else {      
        ((AQuery)localAQuery.id(R.id.iconItem)).progress(R.id.progress).image(arrData.get(position).getImage(), true, false, 0, 0, null, AQuery.FADE_IN_NETWORK, 1.0f);
    }





    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: consider using [droidQuery](http://bit.ly/droidquery), and handle the error using one of the *image* or *ajax* methods.

Answer (score 0):

convertView is null when you use it to construct aq. do new aquery after you inflate convertView.